# Change label color when TextInput is in error state

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, mantine

When an input is in error state, the red text appears with the error notification and the inputfield changes it's outline to red. How can I also colour the label of the TextInput red?

Currently only assigned some classes to the TextInput:

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  /* Put your mantine theme override here */
  components: {
    TextInput: TextInput.extend({
      classNames: {
        root: classes["text-input"],
        label: classes["text-input__label"],
        error: classes["text-input__error"],
        input: classes["text-input__input"]
      }
    })
  }
});
```

This is my mantine form:

```
const form = useForm({
        initialValues: {
            name: ''
        },
        validate: {
            name: (value) => (value.length <= 0) ? (<><Icon type="info" />Name is too short.</>) : value.length > 25 ? 'Name is too long.' : null
        }
    });
```

And some of the applied scss

```
.text-input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  .text-input__label {
    order: -1;
  }

  .text-input__error {
    order: -1;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: Can you share more regarding `classes["text-input__error"]`? As in what css are you using with that classname? Plus, I don't see you writing a label anywhere in the code.

Comment: That's the thing, the label is a built in element within the Mantine TextInput. and whenever there's an error, the label and error p get altered styling, but I don't know how to target the label when that happens. I added the styling in the question. But the classes come from SCSS modular scss.

Comment: https://mantine.dev/core/text-input/#styles-api Have a look at this. You can target `.label` in the SASS. Can't you just use `color` then?

Comment: The thing I want to tackle is applying styling to the label only when the other elements in the div get the error styling.

Comment: When there is an error, the parent has the attribute: `data-error="true"`, can you select the label like this`data-error="true" .label`?